# Movie database is shown instead of database content after restarting Neo4j process

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j 2.3.2 CE server (not embedded) on Windows 7.

I am experiencing a strange behavior. If I stop and restart the Neo4j server process and start the database with the last used database directory, the demo movie database is shown in the web GUI even though the directory still contains my database. After renaming the directory, and starting the database with the new directory name, my database contents are shown again.

Steps to reproduce:

(1) Start the Neo4j server process

(2) Start the server with an empty directory as database location

(3) In web GUI check that database is empty

(4) In web GUI add some data

(5) Stop server and server process

(6) Start server process

(7) Start server with the same directory as above

(8) Check the database contents > now it contains the movie demo database!

(9) Stop server

(10) Rename the database directory

(11) Start server with the new directory name

(12) The database now contains the data added in (4)

Any one has a solution, or at least an explanation?

Gergely

Answer (score 0):

Check what's in config file.

**conf/neo4j-server.properties**
`org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db`

Comment: This does not work in CE, however thanks, as your answer helped me to find the solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the solution.

When Neo4j CE is started, the *Database Location* field contains the last used directory. However **this is a trap**. The effective database location is the default directory, which is `C:\Users\your_user_name\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb`. You have to click *Choose* and select the directory again. I had the movie database in this directory, hence the behavior above.

Note: the `org.neo4j.server.database.location` property of the server configuration file `C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j-server.properties` seems to be ignored in Neo4j CE.